# Joomla artciles showing today's date in front-end

Tags: joomla

does anyone know why all (blog) articles in Joomla are showing the same created date (today's date) in the front-end. However, when i check in the admin (back-end) the dates seem to be fine.

I've cleared the cache (in the Joomla cache manager) as suggested by some forums but it's still showing today's date. any ideas? thanks

Comment: I believe answer to this can only be given by having a look at the code. I assume we need to have a look at com_content component and see how it displays date on the site side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked to me, after few hours scratching my head...

Go to:
/public_html/site_folder/templates/template_name/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php

Locate line 36 (for me) and replace **article** with **item**, like this:

OLD: **article**->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2')); ?>

NEW: **item**->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2')); ?>

Regards,
João Taleço

Comment: +1. I had to modify blog_item.php under "section" folder not "category" but the fix was spot on. thanks for that